# MFC: Best place to prevent a window from re-appearing from a Restore operation

Tags: c++, mfc

When my application is minimized, and the application programmatically closes a child window, the state of the child window between my framework and MFC goes out of sync because MFC will not send a `WM_SHOWWINDOW` message when the application is minimized.  I noticed that Qt had the same problem:  https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/93410/

Things that I have tried:

- Override `OnShowWindow()` -- if the states are out of sync, then I alter the `BOOL` parameter before passing it to the `CDialog::OnShowWindow`.  But doing so does nothing.  It is as if the `BOOL` parameter given to the override is read-only.
- Handle `WM_SHOWWINDOW` in `PreTranslateMessage` -- this does not work because `WM_SHOWWINDOW` does not appear here.

I know I can check `SW_PARENTOPENING` to know when to look for out-of-sync problems and handle it, but I just don't know where is the best place to do it.

My current solution is to override `OnShowWindow`, check for `SW_PARENTOPENING`, then post a `SW_HIDE`.  It works, but it feels like a waste because I should be able to prevent it from restoring entirely rather than defer it.

Summary:

> Basically, I am just programmatically closing a window, say from a timer call, or user's remote command, or whatever, while the main application is minimized. The dialog will be temporarily hidden when minimized (the MFC framework will automatically call ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) but with an internal flag to re-open when the app is restored). If my program sends ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) now, this call will not be registered, and the window will be re-opened by MFC when the app is maximized. To my user, he/she has closed the window remotely and does not expect the window to re-appear, so I need to re-call my ignored ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) somehow when restoring the main app.

Comment: When you close a "child" window (I'm assuming, you are referring to an owned window here), the default message handler calls `DestroyWindow`. You seem to have opted against the default, and are now trying to fix up your hacks. I'd recommend that you go with the flow (instead of fighting the system).

Comment: It's not clear what you are talking about. You should show some minimal code. Try `ON_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39771342/4603670) to catch the messages sooner if that helps.

Comment: The `ON_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` solution is a good workaround, although I won't get `SW_PARENTOPENING` to know for sure that we are doing a "restore".  But it's close enough.

Comment: Why aren't you then destroying those windows you want gone, instead of setting flags, waiting for `ShowWindow` calls to evaluate them, and only then destroy those windows? It just doesn't make sense. Just call `DestroyWindow` (or send a `WM_CLOSE` message) and be done with it.